# Wait for ajax call to complete on page refresh

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am uploading files in ajax async calls, but if during that we refresh page, it gets aborted and files are not get uploaded.
Is there any way to let ajax calls complete before refreshing page, or it gets complete in background

Comment: the refresh of page ideally abort the ajax request.

what you can do is, put an alert message in jquery to confirm whether user want to abort the request or not

Answer (score 0):

Neither request will complete in background, nor you can stop user from closing or refreshing the page.
Use a global javascript variable to determine if ajax calls are completed.

```
var fileUploadComplete = false;

// executed on completion of last outstanding ajax call.
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    fileUploadComplete = true;
});

window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    if (fileUploadComplete) {
        return true;
    }
    else { return confirm("Files are being uploaded, Are you sure want to cancel ?"); }
};
```

Comment: I don't want user to get alert, instead is it possible before unloading system wait for all ajax calls to get completed?

Comment: I don't think there is a way you can force page from getting closed at before ajax at all. Although you can determine if ajax are completed yet and do accordingly. I've updated my answer.